# Why MySQL table auto_increment is reset to 0?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, centos

Today I found the `auto_increment` value of several tables are reset to 0. Why?

- Rails 2.3.x
- MySql 5.0.x

Information:

- the tables are usually empty (rows are created and then deleted)
- the server was `init 6`

The app depends on the auto_increment id and so I'd like to know prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess: you are using InnoDB.

The InnoDB storage engine [stores the auto increment count in memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html); it is reset when MySQL is restarted.

A solution is storing the highest value in a table somewhere and restoring it on system startup. Or, depending on your use case, you may find it useful to keep a single MyISAM table around just to provide `AUTO_INCREMENT` values.

You can find a compilation of [fun facts about `AUTO_INCREMENT` here](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/did-you-know-this-about-auto_increment/).

Comment: Yes, it's InnoDB. Can I solve the problem by convert the table from InnoDB to MyISAM?

Comment: @ohho, you can, but you'll lose all the features that InnoDB has and MyISAM hasn't, like support for transactions and referential integrity. I don't know if you use any of those.

Comment: thanks very much for the information and explanation. I will review the code and proceed accordingly.